# MVC5 Foreach Show/Hide based on date

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a section for my website that is showing upcoming events and I want to make it display only the events (essentially just divs) that have a date greater than today. I am just not sure how to do such a thing.

Here is the code in my partial view:

```
         <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Upcoming Events and Training</h1>
        <div class="row" style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
            @if (Model.CDSContent != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.CDSContent)
                {   
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; height: 100px; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding: 20px;">
                        <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="height: 100px; font-size: 1.5em; padding-top: 15px;">@Html.Raw(item["eventsdate"])</div>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"><a href="@Html.Raw(item["eventsattachment"])" target="_blank">
                                <h3>@Html.Raw(item["eventstitle"])</h3>
                                <p>Click here to find out more.</p>
                                </a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont forget to mark the response as an answer if it helped you solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

One very simplistic approach is to utilize some conditional Razor rendering with the DateTime.Compare method [See MSDN Documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Assuming the item["eventsdate"] object is of type DateTime, then you can do this:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Upcoming Events and Training</h1>
    <div class="row" style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
        @if (Model.CDSContent != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.CDSContent)
            {   
                @if(DateTime.Compare(item["eventsdate"], DateTime.Now) > 0)
                {
                <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; height: 100px; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding: 20px;">
                    <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="height: 100px; font-size: 1.5em; padding-top: 15px;">@Html.Raw(item["eventsdate"])</div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"><a href="@Html.Raw(item["eventsattachment"])" target="_blank">
                            <h3>@Html.Raw(item["eventstitle"])</h3>
                            <p>Click here to find out more.</p>
                            </a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            }
        }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Only problem I am guessing my item is not the correct type as it doesn't work. The error message in Visual Studio says; "The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Compare(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Yea, you really need to know what type you're working with. You could debug the application, put a breakpoint on the DateTime.Compare line and determine the type from there. For example if it is a string then you can convert it to a DateTime type. See [here for documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)